# Unclear struct definition in a C++ header file

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to C++, coming from a Python background.
I have the following header file:

```
struct Example 
{
 int n_example;
 float random_number;
 float second_random_number;

 Example(int n_example, float random_number, float second_random_number);
};
```

I do not get what the second to last line do (i.e, `Example(int n_example, float random_number, float second_random_number);`  )

Might be a super silly question, but it is the first time that I encounter such syntax in C++.
Indeed, normally for struct definition I am used to something like:

```
struct Example 
    {
     int n_example;
     float randon_number;
     float second_random_number;
    };
```

Comment: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/85-constructors/

Comment: I have removed the C tag for you. One thing to note is that C and C++ are different languages. In this case for example, the code is invalid in C but valid for C++.

Comment: @kaylum thank you. I naively thought that this code would have run as well in C.

Comment: Regardless it's always best to stick to a single language tag which is most relevant. Except for very rare cross-language issues. Failing to do this will earn down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this here

```
 Example(int n_example, float random_number, float second_randon_number);
```

is the declaration of the constructor, you can call that and pass the parameters every time you want to construct a new instance of the class Example...

like

```
int main()
{
    Example foo(0, 3.14f, 2.77f);
}
```

the only thing you are missing is the implementation of that constructor...

it may look like this (depending on what version of c++ you are using):

```
Example(int n_example, float random_number, float second_random_number) : 
n_example{n_example}, 
random_number{random_number}, 
second_random_number{second_random_number}, 
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line you're questioning is a class constructor and as far as I'm aware is something equivalent to `__init__` in Python. The reason it's declared in the class definition body - between `{}` - is because C++ is strongly typed, which means that the class definitions has to be fully specified. You cannot "add" new functionality afterwards, during a runtime of a program. Contrary to C++, Python belongs to loosely typed group of languages where you can define classes' fields and methods on the go during a runtime which makes it more flexible but more error-prone in the end.

Also be aware that this is just a simple declaration which should be included within the header file .h The definition of this constructor most of the time (unless `inlined`) will end up in respective `.cpp` file which consist of all the logic related to the class. This separation of declaration `.h` and definition `.cpp` files is one of the building blocks of the language. In the end only the `.cpp` files are compiled and then linked together resulting in a hopefully working application.